# How to prove the following summation formula?

Tags: summation, combinations

Simple summation involving binomial coefficients: $$\sum_{y=0}^{n-1}\sum_{x=0}^{n-1} {x+y \choose x}{2(n-1)-(x+y) \choose (n-1)-x} = n{2n-1 \choose n}$$ I have thought of it for a while and have only reached the conclusion that: $$\sum_{x=0}^{n-1} {x+y \choose x}{2(n-1)-(x+y) \choose (n-1)-x} = {2n-1 \choose n}$$ Please help me prove (or disprove) these statements.

Comment: Have you tried induction on $n$?

Comment: Note that your last summation is, a priori, dependent of $y$.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your second equation holds for any $y$, then you are done: this means that
$$
\sum_{y=0}^{n-1}\sum_{x=0}^{n-1}\binom{x+y}{x}\binom{2n-(x+y)}{n-x}=\sum_{y=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{n}=n\binom{2n-1}{n},
$$
since the second sum is simply a sum of $n$ copies of $\binom{2n-1}{n}$.

However: that being said, the result you want us to prove is not true: consider $n=3$. Then
$$
3\cdot\binom{2\cdot3-1}{3}=30
$$
and
$$
\sum_{y=0}^{2}\sum_{x=0}^{2}\binom{x+y}{x}\binom{6-(x+y)}{3-x}=90.
$$